# How to append successful AJAX response to Drop down values in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, drop-down-menu

After a successful response, I want to update list item values without page reloading. Right now, I have to reload page for every successful response. But I want that it will automatically be updated after add/remove/update successful response.

Here is my list items which comes in foreach loop

```
<li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item mini_cart_item clearfix  ">
<a href="#" onclick="removeCart({{ $cart->id }})"
    class="remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="Remove this item">
<span class="lnr lnr-cross-circle"></span>
</a>
<a href="{{ route('shop.view', [$cart->FoodItem->id]) }}"
    class="image-holder">
<img src=" {{ asset('/storage/items/food/' . $cart->FoodItem->image) }}"
    class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image "
    alt="" height="40" width="40">
<span class="product-name">{{ $cart->FoodItem->name }}</span>
</a>
<span class="quantity">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span
    class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>{{ $cart->price }}
{{-- <span
    class="data{{ $cart->id }}"></span>
--}}
</span>
<span class="qty{{ $cart->id }}">x{{ $cart->quantity }}</span>
{{-- <span class="data{{ $cart->id }}">
</span> --}}
</span>
```

Here is my ajax, I'm trying this way
success: function(response) {
if (response.status == true) {

```
                    $(".data").append(
                            "<li class='woocommerce-mini-cart-item mini_cart_item clearfix'>" +
                            "<a href='#'class='remove remove_from_cart_button' aria-label='Remove this item'><span class='lnr lnr-cross-circle'></span></a>" +
                            "<a href='#' class='image-holder'><img src='/storage/items/food/" +
                            response.data.product_image +
                            "'class='attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image'height='40' width='40'>" +
                            "<span class='product-name'>" + response.data.product_name +
                            "</span></a><span class='quantity'><span class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount'><span class='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol'>" +
                            "$</span>" + response.data.price + "</span><span>x" + response.data
                            .quantity +
                            "</span></span></li>"
                        );
```

How to solved that issue?

Comment: Hi, so what doesn't work here ?

Comment: when adding an item it works. That's fine. But the problem is when I want to add the same item again, it doesn't increase quantity, I have to refresh the page. But I don't want to refresh, I want to update that without refresh.

Comment: so you are able to add new items via ajax to your `dom` ? where is `qty` code  and what do you mean by *doesn't increase quantity..* ? Please elaborate more on your issue .

Comment: Yes, I'm adding item via ajax.                         $(".qty" + response.data.id + "").html(response.data.quantity);

Comment: so that are not added sucessfully ? Did you tried printing `response.data.id` value ? is the value correct ? Also try like this `$(".qty" + response.data.id).html(response.data.quantity);` see if that works

Comment: I got this value, but it did not add automatically. After refresh the page, It works. but I don't want to refresh the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227938/discussion-between-swati-and-prince).

Comment: u can try append method on id